# Detecting anomalous sinusoidal pattern in a timeseries dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science, artificial-intelligence

[fig1. image of what the dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxFZC.png)

[fig2. image of a company ticker with an anomolous sinusoidal data pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OV34.png)

My problem is that I'd like to find other company tickers within the dataframe I have present, fig1. where I can detect a sinusoidal wave pattern such as shown by company BFE IM Equity in fig2.

Now it may be the case that BFE IM Equity is the only company that has such a timeseries pattern however I would still like to come up with a full proof method that would also detect BFE IM Equity itself.

I have tried various ways, I've made an attempt with K-means clustering hoping that company tickers would get clustered alongside BFE IM Equity, this was not the case.

I tried fourier transforms and using autocorrelation however I am not a very mathsy person and arrived at a dead end with these.

Comment: tsfresh is a good resource https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh

Comment: You showed a pretty extreme case. Surely computing the variance suffices? Also, Wall Street quants have a rich literature on volatility measures.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation coefficient ended up working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).